# LibreOffice Calc Macro: printing a sheet gives 'no such method or property: $(ARG1)"

Tags: printing, libreoffice, basic, calc

I have a spreadsheet containing data in lines on several sheets. These sheets are named arbitrarily (not sheet1 sheet2 nor any similar scheme).

I need to extract some info from one of the lines of the current sheet (I give the number of the line in an input box), then put this info on another sheet to format it, then print that formatted sheet, and finally go back to the initial sheet I was on (one of those containing data).

So far I have come up with this code: (I omit the line selection and data copying because that works)

```
 '   Sheets("facture").PrintOut

Dim oDoc as Object
oDoc=ThisComponent
Dim sPrefix$  ' Prefix used to identify the print listener routines.
Dim sService$ ' Print listener service name

sPrefix="print_listener_"
sService="com.sun.star.view.XPrintJobListener"
If NOT oDoc.sheets().hasByName("facture") Then
  MsgBox "Le document n'a pas de page nommée 'facture'"
Else
 Dim oSheets
 oSheets = oDoc.Sheets
 Dim currentSheet
 currentSheet = oDoc.getcurrentcontroller.activesheet

 oDoc.currentController.setActiveSheet(oSheets.getByName("facture"))
 oPrintListener=CreateUnoListener(sPrefix,sService)
 oDoc.addPrintJobListener(oPrintListener)
 'oPrintJobListnerDoc=oDoc
 oDoc.Print(Array())

 wait 12000
  
 oDoc.currentController.setActiveSheet(currentSheet)
```

However, when I run it, the data is correctly formated on my output sheet, but the VB window pops up with 'BASIC runtime error: property or meethod not found: $(ARG1)'.

If I remove the 'wait 12000' and 'oDoc.currentController.setActiveSheet(currentSheet)' then the data is printed correctly but Calc stays on the output sheet, and doesn't get back tot the initial sheet I was on (obviously).

If I only remove the 'wait 12000', nothing happens, and the data is not printed.

Can anybody help? Thanks!

Comment: Creating an event listener assumes that there are two more procedures somewhere in your code - `print_listener_printJobEvent (evt)` and `print_listener_disposing ()`. The first one should receive through the parameter evt.State = 1 and realizing that the printing was completed successfully, somehow tell the main program that there is no need to wait any longer and return to the active page. The second procedure usually does nothing, but it must be present in the code. And don't forget to remove the listener after you finish printing with `.removePrintJobListener(oPrintListener)`

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer, I'll try it but by procedures, I guess you mean functions defined by 'Sub print_listener_printJobEvent(evt)' ?

Comment: OP here, by just adding the subs 'Sub print_listener_printJobEvent (evt) End Sub' and 'Sub print_listener_disposing () End Sub' with empty bodies it know works (I reduced the wait to 900, and there doesn't seem to be the need to wait on printing finishing, I don't know if Basic has semaphores or whatever...) Anyway thanks, JohnSUN, my problem is solved for now!

Answer (score 0):

The general principle of waiting for the end of printing can be expressed as follows

```
REM  *****  BASIC  *****
Public Statex1 As Integer   ' Through this variable, the event handling procedure will notify the main program
Public oPrintJobListnerDoc As Variant

Sub PrintOutFacture()
Dim oDoc As Variant
    oDoc=ThisComponent
    Statex1=0
    oPrintJobListnerDoc = CreateUnoListener("print_listener_", "com.sun.star.view.XPrintJobListener")
    oDoc.addPrintJobListener(oPrintJobListnerDoc)
Rem ...Prepare the print - fill the cells with the desired values, format, define the print area, etc.
    oDoc.Print(Array()) ' It might not be an empty array, but a whole bunch of print options!
    While Statex1=0 ' 1 = Printing completed, 3 = Print canceled
       Wait 100
    Wend
    oDoc.removePrintJobListener(oPrintJobListnerDoc)
Rem ...Post-Print Actions - Switch the sheet, close the document, or do something else
End Sub

Sub print_listener_printJobEvent(oEvent As Variant)
   Statex1 = oEvent.State   ' Pass the value of the State field of the oEvent to the main program through the Public variable Statex1
End Sub

Sub print_listener_disposing
End Sub
```